# Snapkit, stick UILabel to bottom

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I have a scrollview with a couple of elements inside. I must set the bottom label to stick to the bottom of the view no matter what but should not overlap with the view on top of it which happens when the screen is small.

How do I achieve this in Snapkit?

Comment: Do you want this label be in scrollview as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift 4:

```
someScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let stickyLabel = UILabel()
stickyLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
stickyLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stickyLabel.text = "some sticky bottom label"
self.view.addSubview(stickyLabel)

someScrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
}

stickyLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.top.equalTo(someScrollView.snp.bottom).offset(4)
    make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(4)
    make.bottom.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-4)
}
```

would give something like:

[image: sticky bottom view]